# How to save countdown timer for each element in the array with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, countdowntimer

I have a table that renders`patientInfo array`. Then I have a `countDown component`that counts downs starting from 15mins. This countDown only renders when the `patient.locationInfo` column and patient.status column isn't empty. So each `table row` has individual countDown counting down from 15mins. What I need to do is save the countdown on state(obsDue) for individually patient in the array. When the countDown gets to 14mins, I need to disable buttons on `Patient Location` column for each row.

I'm not sure how to execute this. I thought of onChange event, but it doesn't work as I'm not working with input/form alike elements. I can get the count down time displayed by `document.getElementById('count-down').textContent` but that's as far as I’ve got to

```
PatientInfo Array

patientInfo = [
           { room: "1", name: 'John Nero', obsDue: '', locationInfo: '', status: ''},
           { room: "2", name: 'Shawn Michael', obsDue: '', locationInfo: '', status: ''},
           { room: "3", name: 'Gereth Macneil', obsDue: '', locationInfo: '', status: ''},
           { room: "4", name: 'Elminster Shaw', obsDue: '', locationInfo: '', status: ''},
           { room: "5", name: 'Rincewind Hatcher', obsDue: '', locationInfo: '', status: ''},
```

```
PatientRow component

<tbody>
               {patientInfo.map((patient, index) =>
                   <tr key={index} >
                       <td className=`patientNameRow text-center `>{patient.room}</td>
                       <td className=`patientNameRow>{patient.name}</td>

                       <td className=`patientNameRow `>{patient.status}</td>
                       <td id="count-down-row" className=`patientNameRow `}>{patient.locationInfo !== '' && patient.status !== '' ? <countDown /> : ''} </td>
                       <td className=`location-btns `>
                          <Button onClick={// sets patient.locationInfo }> garden  </Button>
                          <Button onClick={// sets patient.locationInfo }> TV </Button>
                       </td> 
<td className=`patient-status `>
                          <Button onClick={// sets patient-status }> garden  </Button>
                          <Button onClick={// sets patient-status }> TV </Button>
                       </td> 

<tbody>
```

```
countDown component

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';


const countDown= () => {
   const [currentCount, setCount] = useState(950000);
   const timer = () => setCount(currentCount - 1000);

   useEffect(
       () => {
           if (currentCount <= -15) {
               return;
           }
           const id = setInterval(timer, 1000);
           return () => clearInterval(id);
       },
       [currentCount] 
   );
   return <div><span>{moment(currentCount).format('mm')}min</span></div>;
};

export default countDown;
```

Comment: "What I need to do is save the countdown on state(obsDue) for individually patient in the array."  Is that a requirement? Or is the `countdown` used for the sole purpose of `disabling` the button?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make use of [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)? When you load the page you can initilize and store individual patient. When the countdown hits 14mininutes, you can access that database and set value of "disableButton" to true.

Then in your javascript you could check for that value, and if that value is set to true you'd simply execute your logic.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract a custom hook from `countDown`, say `useCountDown` instead of returning a component (return `currentCount` instead).
2. You can create a child component for `tr` elements, say `PatientStatus` created in a map.
3. Within the `PatientStatus`, use the `currentCount` from `useCountDown` hook and disable when the `currentCount` reaches 14.

Each `useCountDown` is a state of within each `PatientStatus`, so should be able to disable button within the component.

You can do something like below (not tested).

```
const useCountDown = () => {
  const [currentCount, setCount] = useState(950000);
  const timer = () => setCount(currentCount - 1000);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentCount <= -15) return;

    const id = setInterval(timer, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, [currentCount]);
  return currentCount;
};

function PatientStatus() {
  const currentCount = useCountDown();

  const disableOnCountDown = () => currentCount < 14;

  return (
    <tr>
      <td className="patientNameRow text-center">{patient.room}</td>
      <td className="patientNameRow">{patient.name}</td>

      <td className="patientNameRow">{patient.status}</td>
      <td id="count-down-row" className="patientNameRow">
        {""}
      </td>
      <td className="location-btns ">
        <Button disabled={shouldDisable} onClick={() => {}}>
          garden
        </Button>
        <Button disabled={shouldDisable} onClick={() => {}}>
          TV
        </Button>
      </td>
      <td className="patient-status ">
        <Button disabled={shouldDisable} onClick={() => {}}>
          garden
        </Button>
        <Button disabled={shouldDisable} onClick={() => {}}>
          TV
        </Button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
}

function PatientRow() {
  return (
    <tbody>
      {patientInfo.map((patient, index) => (
        <PatientStatus key={patient.room} />
      ))}
    </tbody>
  );
}
```